# WMI With ServerNetworkProtocol is not working vb.net

Tags: vb.net, wmi

I have this piece of code , I am using WMI to get the ServerNetworkProtocol in vb.net and it does not perform any exception but  mgmtcls.GetInstances() returns not a single value , Is there anyway else or is there anything wrong with this

```
' Specify server, SQL WMI namespace and class name    
Dim mgmtPath As New ManagementPath()
mgmtPath.Server = "MAIN"
mgmtPath.NamespacePath = "root\Microsoft\SqlServer\ComputerManagement10" 'For SQL 2008    
mgmtPath.ClassName = "ServerNetworkProtocol"
' Get instances of the ServerNetworkProtocol class
Dim mgmtcls As New ManagementClass(mgmtPath)
Dim mgmtColl As ManagementObjectCollection = mgmtcls.GetInstances()
'Enumerates ServerNetworkProtocol info
For Each mgmtObj As ManagementObject In mgmtColl
    Dim svc As String = String.Format("{0}", mgmtObj("Enabled"))
    MsgBox(svc)
Next
```

Comment: `Dim searcher As ManagementObjectSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\Microsoft\SqlServer\ComputerManagement10", "SELECT * FROM ServerNetworkProtocol") For Each obj As ManagementObject In searcher.Get() MessageBox.Show(obj("Enabled")) Next`. Set the Target CPU to `AnyCPU` and un-tick `Prefer 32-bit` if it's selected.

Comment: the Any CPU thing was the problem ... thank you man